# Frontend plugin which is included via typoScript does not work in TYPO3 8.7 anymore

Tags: typo3-8.x

in TYPO3 7.6 I defined a Frontend Plugin which is of type "PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT".

**ext_localconf.php:**

```
ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyVendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Maildownload',
    ['Maildownload' => 'show'],
    [],
    ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT
);
```

the configurePlugin method creates a typoScript Setup, where the the "run()" method of Extbase's Bootstrap class is called:

```
...
tt_content.myext_maildownload.20 = USER
tt_content.myext_maildownload20.userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
...
```

This means Extbase processes the request by calling the action "show" in the controller "Maildownload" of my extension.

I Call my plugin via ajax. That means, I define a page with a separate typenum and include the plugin via typoScript:

**setup.ts**:

```
ajax_page = PAGE
ajax_page {
  typeNum = 123
  config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
  config.metaCharset = UTF-8
  config.debug = 0
  config.additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
  config.xhtml_cleaning = 0
  config.adminPanel = 0

  10 < tt_content.myext_maildownload
}
```

When I call the page index.php?type=123 the action "show" in the controller "Maildownload" will be executed.

**After upgrading to TYPO3 8.7 this behaviour has obviously changed.**

The generated typoScript code of the "configurePlugin()" method is still the same. When I call page index.php?type=123 TYPO3 renders it like an ordinary content element and does not call the TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run method anymore. So my showAction method will not be called.

I could define a dataProcessor class now and move the showAction into it.
But that is not a great solution, because I don't want to bypass the complete extbase renderering process.

Is there now a new way to include my plugin into the page so that it will be treated like an extbase plugin and not like a content element?

Comment: define the pluginName,vendorName to the tt_content.myext_maildownload20. and if you don't have in url controller and action name use switchableControllerActions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andrei thank you for your reply, but it did not hit the point.

Meanwhile I found out that the cause for the problem was this breaking change in TYPO3 8.5: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78002-EnforceCHashArgumentForExtbaseActions.html?highlight=chash

so a possible solution is to set the requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments to false in the typoScript plugin settings:

```
plugin.tx_myextension {

   features.requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 0

   ...

}
```